# Extending UIGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to extend UIGestureRecognizer in Swift, I want all gestures to be affected by this.

If I do.

```
 extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    public override var state: UIGestureRecognizerState {

     get {

        return self.state

     }

     set(newState) {

        self.handleStateChange(newState)

     }

   }
}
```

It only works if I do a but only for `Pan`, `LongPress` or whatever gesture I want to be affected.  I can't do it for all. If I do it for all then it comes back with the error.

```
'Property does not override any property from its superclass'
'Getter for 'state' with Objective-C selector 'state' conflicts with method 'state()' with the same Objective-C selector.
```

If I remove `override` it just comes back with the bottom error.  I am looking for an answer in Swift.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you want is a subclass. A subclass can override properties from its superclass.

```
class MyPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    override var state: UIGestureRecognizerState {
        get {
            return self.state
        }

        set(newState) {
            print(newState)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to affect all gestures so creating a new subclass won't help.

Comment: You can create a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` (which is itself a superclass of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`) and override its state property. Then you can use this subclass throughout your code.

Comment: That will just create another child class of UIGestureRecognizer but it won't affect the parent which needs to be affected.

Comment: Right. You will still need to write subclasses for each specific gesture you'd like to use, and those subclasses can inherit from your `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass.